# Postgresql: how to create a View combining regular Tables A, B, C and pivoted table D with a json field?

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-11

I have created a **standard view, VIEW,** that includes different fields from different tables:

```
SELECT e.id AS "Employee Id",
  concat(e.first_name,' ',e.additional_family_name,' ',e.family_name) AS "Full name",
  e.status AS "Status",
  e.personal_email AS "Email",
  ejp.contract_start_date AS "Start Date",
  ejp.contract_end_date AS "End Date",
  ejp.area_id AS "Area id",
  ejp.area_name AS "Area",
  c.name AS "Company",
  h.name AS "Headquarter",

FROM employees e
 LEFT JOIN employee_job_positions ejp on e.id = ejp.employee_id
 LEFT JOIN company_users cu on e.company_user_id = cu.id
 LEFT JOIN companies c on cu.company_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN headquarters h on c.id = h.company_id
```

I have a **table, EMPLOYEE_FIELDS, that includes a Json field** that I need to pivot and include in my view:

```
SELECT employee_id, field_name, value
FROM employee_fields
ORDER BY employee_id
```

that gives result similar to this:

```
ID  FIELD_NAME          VALUE
1   vacation_days       {"value":"10"}
1   compensation_type   {"entity":"compensation_type","id":"mixed"}
1   contract_end_date   {"value":"2019-12-31"}
1   contract_start_date {"value":"2013-05-23"}
1   ...                 ...
2   vacation_days       {"value":"10"}
2   compensation_type   {"entity":"compensation_type","id":"fixed"}
2   contract_end_date   {"value":"2019-12-31"}
2   contract_start_date {"value":"2007-09-26"}
2   ...                 ...
```

**I need to pivot the table EMPLOYEE_FIELDS** and add each line as a column, matching the corresponding value of the EMPLOYEE_FIELDS.ID to the VIEW.ID.

I have **tried adding a CASE WHEN statement** to my initial VIEW creation request, e.g the following:

```
SELECT e.id AS "Employee Id",
  concat(e.first_name,' ',e.additional_family_name,' ',e.family_name) AS "Full name",
  e.status AS "Estatus",
  e.personal_email AS "Email",
  ejp.contract_start_date AS "Start Date",
  ejp.contract_end_date AS "End Date",
  ejp.area_id AS "Area id",
  ejp.area_name AS "Area",
  c.name AS "Company",
  h.name AS "Headquarter",
  (CASE WHEN ef.field_name='birthdate' THEN ef.value END) AS "Fecha de nacimiento",
  (CASE WHEN ef.field_name='gender' THEN ef.value END) AS "Genero"
FROM employees e
 LEFT JOIN employee_job_positions ejp on e.id = ejp.employee_id
 LEFT JOIN company_users cu on e.company_user_id = cu.id
 LEFT JOIN companies c on cu.company_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN headquarters h on c.id = h.company_id
```

but because I cannot group on a field that is a json I get the following result:

```
Id |Full_Name |Status |Email           |Start_Date |End_Date   |Area_Id |Area     |Company       |Headquarter        |Birthdate                    |Gender
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |NULL                         |NULL
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |NULL                         |NULL
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |NULL                         |NULL
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |NULL                         |"{""value"":""Femenino"",""id"":""female""}"
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |"{""value"":""1984-01-13""}" |NULL
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |NULL                         |NULL
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |NULL                         |NULL
```

where you can see that a line is created for each FIELD_NAME present in the EMPLOYEE_FIELDS table instead of grouping everything for a given ID...

**How could I modify my query/handle the json field to get a proper outcome?**
(proper outcome should be like that:

```
Id |Full_Name |Status |Email           |Start_Date |End_Date   |Area_Id |Area     |Company       |Headquarter        |Birthdate                    |Gender  
1  |FN+LN     |active |email@email.com |2013-05-23 |2019-12-31 |3       |Sales    |Company name  |Address in Mexico  |"{""value"":""1984-01-13""}" |"{""value"":""Femenino"",""id"":""female""}"
```

Comment: STP, don't use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) in questions - many reasons for this.

Comment: Happy to change the table screenshots to "code". Any suggestion on how to do that @Vérace ?

Comment: Just have it as formatted text! There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? p.s. bienvenu au forum! :-)

Comment: Done @Vérace! I hope that you we'll find it easier to answer my question now ;-)